# Pychrome ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=8000): Max retries exceeded with url: /json/new

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, testing

I have been using Pychrome and Chrome Dev tool protocol to check for network requests in chrome dev tools. It was working successfully yesterday. I have made no changes and today I have started to get this error

```
ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=8000): Max retries exceeded with url: /json/new (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x102b5e0a0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused'))
```

I have tried killing anything running on any ports, checked the 8000 was free and all good. Going and using the sample basic script given by pychrome here https://github.com/fate0/pychrome I still get the same error. So It must be something on my machine causing an issue but can figure out why it worked find yesterday and not today. Using the script give on pychromes git page. Its failing for me on step `tab = browser.new_tab()`

All suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is this URL `/json/new`? Where are you telling to hit that and how is it supposed to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised now that I never started the other headless browser. For pychrome to read the network tab, it starts on headless browser and then in the other it goes to the site you want. One is basically reading the other. So basically starting the chrome browser worked first as a sort of server fixed.

```
sudo /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --headless --disable-gpu --remote-debugging-port=8000
```

Thats how its started on Mac at least. I think its easier on linux.